# How to save tablib dataset as csv file?

Tags: python, excel, csv, tablib

I have created a dataset using tablib.

`out_dict` is a dictionary file

```
headers = out_dict.keys()
data = tablib.Dataset(out_dict.values(), headers=headers)
```

How can I save it as a csv file in the same format?

Comment: Read [exporting-data `Comma-Separated Values`](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/master/tutorial/#exporting-data)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [`Exporting Data`](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/master/tutorial/#exporting-data) tablib documentation, a dataset can be exported in a number of different formats. To export to CSV format use:

```
data.export('csv')
```

Or directly to a file using:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    f_output.write(data.csv)
```

Comment: Seems to be that way now:

`with open('my-data.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    f.write(dataset.csv)`